# Pass Select-Object properties to cmdlet

Tags: arrays, string, function, powershell, arguments

I need to pass properties to a cmdlet. That is, one call I may use

```
$SelList = "ProcessName,Handles"
```

then

```
get-process | select $sellist
```

-- Which fails.  My assumption is this should be a string array, not a string. And this is to be done on a function call, so the next call might use

```
$SelList = "ProcessName,Handles,ID"
```

Passing a single value e.g. `$SelList = "ProcessName"` seems to work.  My assumption is I am (really, really) overlooking something here.  Is a little ForEach loop within "Select-Object" used?  It would seem overkill, but (as mentioned) I'm sure I'm overlooking something.

Comment: I regard this as answered; the real cause of the problem was a typo.

Answer (score 4):

So why don't you pass in an array?

```
$filter = @('ProcessName','Handles','ID')
get-process | select $filter
```

Also, `Get-Help Select-Object` reveals the following:

```
Select-Object [[-Property] <Object[]>]
```

which means it accepts arrays

Comment: I had thought that might be the case, but $CSV1_list   = @('OriginalName','CreatedOn') Import-Csv -Path "out.csv"  -Delimiter ',' | Select -property $CSV1_list | Sort-Object originalname produces blanks following "OriginalName CreatedOn" -- if I use Select Originalname,CreatedOn it works.

Comment: Heck, I believe it.  Using Import-Csv -Path "out.csv" -Delimiter ',' | Select -property * | Sort-Object originalname works.  I need to specify the properties because the ones needed will vary with the file.

Comment: well, i suggest you accept this answer and create a new question, because the question you are having now is a completely different thing

Comment: Yeah, I can't argue with an answer that resolves the syntax ... will have to look into what might be wrong with my array spec.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

just enumerate list values into array like it, @() is not necessary:

```
$filter = 'ProcessName','Handles','ID'
get-process | select $filter
```

Comment: Your answer duplicates @4c74356b41's, only with less explanation (except for omitting `@(…)`, but that's entirely incidental, especially without explaining the difference).
I get that we sometimes miss others' preexisting answers and accidentally duplicate them. Was that the case here? If not, I'd love to know what motivated you to post this answer.

Comment: I agree with you, it's a bit duplicated, it was not my intention. It was only to show that we can make even shorter. I like when the powershell code is simple and short. I will add the mention "shorter";)

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that an array is the method of doing this.  So $SelList = @('ProcessName','Handles') ... in my case, this does not resolve the matter as passing the array still fails.  However, that is a different issue.

Comment: Given that @4c74356b41 has already suggested this very solution, I suggest you delete this answer and accept his (and post a new question about any remaining issues, as has been suggested).

Comment: I'll add a follow-up.  Check the nut behind the wheel.  My description was $Sellist = @('ProcessName','Handles','ID').  That was an (over)simplification.  In reality $Sellist1 = @('ProcessName','Handles','ID') was *supposed* to be followed with a $Sellist2 = @('ProcessName','ID')  ... it does NOT work if you made a typo and what was supposed to be $SelList2 was different "$SelList1" with different stuff altogether.  After I stayed away from the script for a while, I saw it.  I appreciate the correction as i was (obviously) going all over the place tracking down what was not there.

Comment: Your question as it stands now has a clear problem statement and has received useful answers. It will be of most benefit to future readers if you accept one of them (@4c74356b41's is my recommendation). If there was another problem in the mix, and it was a mere typo, mention it as an aside _in your question_, IF you think that it represents a pitfall for others too - rather than being a one-off mistake (I didn't fully understand your comment). You can then delete this answer (if you don't, it may attract more down-votes).